# Split Date from .CSV file: 1/16/2016 to Year: 2016, Day: 16, Month: 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, split, strptime

I have a .csv file that contains columns: NAME, DATE, INFO, STATS, MORE_INFO

I want to import the .csv file (either with Python 3.6 code, or Pandas)

Then I need to filter the columns: NAME, DATE, INFO

Here's where I am having trouble, I need to take the 'DATE' column of my .csv file which lists a date as 1/16/2016 and separate it so I can select only the MONTH for my filtered .csv output file.

My final columns to read like NAME, MONTH, INFO

The entire 'DATE' column is split by two years - 2016 and 2017. I need to take the NAME, MONTH, INFO for 2016 and save it to a new .csv file, and the same thing for 2017 so each year is separated by grouped months.

```
averageData = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep = ',', parse_dates=True)
df1 = averageData.loc[:, ["DATE", "NAME", "INFO"]]
df1["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["DATE"])
stripdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(['01-01-2016'], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The variable stripdate where datetime.datetime.strptime() is supposed to rearrange the date in the right format is where I am misunderstanding something. How do I just group everything by MONTH of the dates listed under the 'DATE' column from my .csv file. Then further group them by year in new .csv files?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01-16-2016','06-24-2016','04-30-2016','07-09-2016','03-21-2017','01-13-2017'],'Parameter':[10,420,60,10,21,33]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

If you would like to add columns to your data with Year: 2016, Day: 16, Month: 1, then try:

```
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['Day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

After that, you can locate dataframes based on year and save to csv.

```
df.loc[df['Year'] == 2016].to_csv('2016.csv')
```

If you would like to group your data per month:

```
df=df.set_index('date')
df1=df.resample("M").sum() # Mean is another option.
```

or

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper("M")).sum()
```